# Java. Why doesn't this for loop work correctly

Tags: java, loops, multidimensional-array, for-loop

I have the next for loop header:

```
for ( int row = interval[intRow][_START_]; row <= interval[intRow][_END_]; row++ )
```

where `interval` is of type/dimension `int[15][5]`, `intRow` is of value 1 and `_START_` and `_END_` are constants, start being 0 and end being 1;

`interval[intRow][_START_]` returns 1 and `interval[intRow][_END_]` returns 2

Why the hell does `row` only go till 1 (so just one loop instead of 2)?

I've noticed that if i put the second condition, or whatever it's called, in between two `( ... )` then it works, it does the loop twice. What i mean is:

```
for ( int row = interval[intRow][_START_]; row <= (interval[intRow][_END_]); row++ )
```

Has anyone got any ideas on why this is happening? I know i can just put them between two parenthesis, but i'd like to know why this doesn't work.

Thanks.

**EDIT1**

It's `<=` not `<` ... I made a typo at the beginning. Sorry.

**EDIT2**

Basically this would look like:

`for ( int row = interval[1][0]; row <= interval[1][1]; row++ )`

where `interval[1][0] == 1` and `interval[1][1] == 2`

Comment: What is inside `interval[1][0];` and `interval[1][1];` ?

Comment: the values 1 and 2 respectively

Comment: Are you sure? Can you print them out?

Comment: I'm afraid so ... using Watch to check out the variables in debug mode ... and they show correctly :( :D Going nuts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried following.

```
int[][] interval = new int [15][5];

int intRow = 1;
int _START_ = 0;
int _END_ = 1;

interval[intRow][_START_] = 1;
interval[intRow][_END_] = 2;

for ( int row = interval[intRow][_START_]; row <= interval[intRow][_END_]; row++ ) {

    System.out.println(row);
}
```

Output:
1
2

TO summarize, its working fine for me. Which makes me wonder if *interval[intRow][_END_]* is being set correctly.

Try using debugger or simply Sysouts to debug your program.

Comment: I am .. and this is why i'm confused :) hehe ... I might be missing something then ... but i can't figure out what. The values in Watch seem legit, it SHOULD go for the next loop, but it doesn't. Except if i put it in between `(...)'

Comment: Can't think of any other reason. Probably paste "java -version" output  here.

Comment: f that...i'll just put it in between paranthesis ... thanks for testing :D that deserves an accept :) lol

Comment: Could you please provide your version details either ways? Are you using Sun Java?

Answer (score 3):

Loop1 : 1<2 - OK
Loop2 : 2<2 - not ok

Try <=

Comment: haha, sorry, it's <= .. i just made a mistake when typing :) sorry

Comment: In other words, the control variable is incremented after the loop executes, and the evaluation occurs before then next iteration of the loop.  First time through 1<2, increment occurs, 2<2 is false, and loop doesn't execute a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to write this ?

```
for ( int row = interval[intRow][_START_]; row <= interval[intRow][_END_]; row++ )
```

or this ?

```
for ( int row = interval[intRow][_START_]; row < interval[intRow][_END_] +1; row++ )
```